# Connecting to sql or oracle server with iOS Device

Tags: php, mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I understand I cannot connect an iOS Device directly to the server and have to go through a web service of some kind. I am using Amazon AWS RDS to house both the sql server and oracle server. I was hoping to house the web server within AWS as well.

I am just not certain where to start.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Amazon AWS might provide some service for accessing DB from the box.

If not, you can write a web service, which will serve as a proxy to your DB.

You might want to write SOAP- or REST-like web service for global compatibility,
or you can just get a simple web-server (i.e. apache) with php running, just for you.
After that you can provide an easy protocol between a device and a web-server:

1. Device uses a browser (CURL) to request information from web service;
2. Web service parses GET/POST parameters recieved, and fetches data from database accordingly;
3. Web service prepares data, serializing it for transportable format. I.e. JSON: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON
4. Device recieves response from web-server, parses it, and uses in application.

If data is sensible, you should consider security measures, including authentification procedure and using secure (crypted) channel between client and server.